# Unbind model from view in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have an audio player class which controls the HTML5 audio player. In that I am monitoring the the audio player events and triggering them to the associated view. On the view file this is how I bind the appropriate events

```
app.audioPlayer.$el.bind('musicEnded', _.bind(this.onMusicEnded, this));
app.audioPlayer.$el.bind('askForNextMusic', _.bind(this.onAskForNextMusic, this));
app.audioPlayer.$el.bind('askForPreviousMusic', _.bind(this.onAskForPreviousMusic, this));
```

Once I move out from this view I want to unbind the events from this view. I tried like this for that

```
app.audioPlayer.$el.unbind('musicEnded', _.bind(this.onMusicEnded, this));
app.audioPlayer.$el.unbind('askForNextMusic', _.bind(this.onAskForNextMusic, this));
app.audioPlayer.$el.unbind('askForPreviousMusic', _.bind(this.onAskForPreviousMusic, this));
```

But it dosent seems to have any effect. How can I properly do this in backbonejs?
Thanks

Comment: If you have more sample code to indicate what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably be of more assistance.

Comment: Any reason your not using the [events hash](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents)? Also have you tried [undelegating](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-undelegateEvents) the events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that you bind/unbind using `_.bind`. As this will always create a new function. So the function you bind and the function you try to unbind are not the same, so unbind will not work.

You have to save a reference to the function you bind, or use `_.bindAll` in the beginning cause this will replace you current function with a binded one. So when ever you use bind/unbind then it is the same function:

```
_.bindAll(this, onMusicEnded) 
// the will replace this.onMusicEnded with _.bind(this.onMusicEnded, this)
app.audioPlayer.$el.bind('musicEnded', this.onMusicEnded);
app.audioPlayer.$el.unbind('musicEnded', this.onMusicEnded);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://backbonejs.org/#Events

Bind a callback function to an object. The callback will be invoked whenever the event is fired.

```
object.on(event, callback, [context])
```

Remove a previously-bound callback function from an object.

```
object.off([event], [callback], [context])
```

Comment: I tried this, but not working. Can you please have a look on the way I bind and tell me whats wrong?

Comment: @Zach if you can post the actual code you want to execute on http://jsfiddle.net/  ,  If you have more sample code to indicate what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably be of more assistance.

Comment: The problem is that the function he tries to unbind is not the same as the one bind. `on` and `off` are just aliases for `bind` and `unbind`.